# Can someone identify this vector representation of $\rm SO(3)$ in terms of multi-variable polynomials?

Tags: angular-momentum, representation-theory, rotation, spherical-harmonics

I am trying to get some deeper intuition for the representations of $\rm SO(3)$ and how they combine with each other, and I ran into an odd object that I'm hoping that folks here might help me identify.

As a general setting, I am considering the combinations of the solid harmonics $$S_{\ell m}(\mathbf r) = r^\ell Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)$$ (which are, conveniently, homogeneous polynomials of degree $\ell$, and are much easier to work with than the $Y_{\ell m}$'s), and I am trying to understands what actually happens, at the coordinate level, when you use Clebsch-Gordan coefficents to combine a set of these into a single representation. That is, I define
$$
F_{\ell_1\ell_2\ell_3}(\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2, \mathbf r_3)
=
\sum_{m_1,m_2,m_3}
⟨\ell_1m_1\ell_2m_2|\ell_3m_3⟩
S_{\ell_1m_1}(\mathbf r_1)
S_{\ell_2m_2}(\mathbf r_2)
S_{\ell_3m_3}(\mathbf r_3)^*
,
$$
which naturally gives a scalar-valued function, and I then look to understand the resulting structure.

---

As a first example, consider the case when $(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3) = (1,1,1)$. It is an easy calculation (meaning: Mathematica can do it easily) to show that
$$
F_{111}(\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2, \mathbf r_3) = c_{111} \mathbf r_1 \cdot (\mathbf r_2 \times \mathbf r_3),
$$
where $c_{111}$ is a boring numerical constant. Similarly, if one takes the slightly more complex example of $(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3) = (1,2,2)$, there is again a simple and pleasing structure:
$$
F_{122}(\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2, \mathbf r_3) = c_{122} \mathbf r_1 \cdot (\mathbf r_2 \times \mathbf r_3)(\mathbf r_2 \cdot\mathbf r_3).
$$

---

My question here is what happens a couple of levels up, at $(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3) = (2,2,3)$. Here the polynomials are no longer something that I can recognize, but Mathematica has very little trouble reducing the scalar function to the following form:
$$
F_{223}(\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2, \mathbf r_3) 
= 
c_{223} 
\left(\mathbf r_1 \cdot (\mathbf r_2 \times \mathbf r_3)\right)
\ 
\mathbf r_1
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 x_2 (y_3^2 + z_3^2 - 4 x_3^2) - 5 y_2 x_3 y_3 - 5 z_2 x_3 z_3 \\
 y_2 (z_3^2 + x_3^2 - 4 y_3^2) - 5 z_2 y_3 z_3 - 5 x_2 x_3 y_3 \\
 z_2 (x_3^2 + y_3^2 - 4 z_3^2) - 5 x_2 x_3 z_3 - 5 y_2 y_3 z_3
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
And this brings me to my real question here: **what *is* that thing on the right?**

It is clear to me that, as a cubic-polynomial function of $\mathbf r_2$ and $\mathbf r_3$, this thing transforms as a vector and it is therefore some kind of $\ell=1$ representation of $\rm SO(3)$. But what representation is this, exactly? Does it have a name? Is there some systematic way to treat it? (Say, analogously to the formalism in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/635248/8563), maybe?) I have tried to get it as clean as I can, but I'm still not super sold on it, and it feels like there should be a better way to express it.

I would be particularly like to know how this object fits within a larger framework, as I would like to keep going to higher $\ell$'s (at least as high as $(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3) = (2,3,4)$) and the more I can understand about the setting, the better.

Comment: Are any symmetries more apparent when written in terms of Wigner 3j symbols?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Not really. When written out in full, whether it be in terms of 3j symbols or Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, the whole thing is a mess. It's only after simplifying that one can factor out the triple product and get polynomials that are small enough to see anything.

Comment: (... but, that said, you are right, 3j symbols are a better approach than Clebsch-Gordan for what I want to do.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, folks, I managed to get this on my own =).

**Short answer:** the vector in question can be expressed as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 x_2 (y_3^2 + z_3^2 - 4 x_3^2) - 5 y_2 x_3 y_3 - 5 z_2 x_3 z_3 \\
 y_2 (z_3^2 + x_3^2 - 4 y_3^2) - 5 z_2 y_3 z_3 - 5 x_2 x_3 y_3 \\
 z_2 (x_3^2 + y_3^2 - 4 z_3^2) - 5 x_2 x_3 z_3 - 5 y_2 y_3 z_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\mathbf r_2 r_3^2-5\mathbf r_3 (\mathbf r_2\cdot\mathbf r_3)
$$
so that the target function reads
$$
F_{223}(\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2, \mathbf r_3) 
= 
c_{223} 
\left(\mathbf r_1 \cdot (\mathbf r_2 \times \mathbf r_3)\right)
\left[
(\mathbf r_1\cdot\mathbf r_2) r_3^2-5(\mathbf r_1\cdot\mathbf r_3)(\mathbf r_2\cdot\mathbf r_3)
\right]
.
$$

**Slightly longer answer.**

How does one get to this?

For one, the vector representation is a bit of a red herring, and it is better to work directly with the scalar form (i.e. the big vector dotted with $\mathbf r_1$), as this allows for more freedom in collecting terms and recognizing patterns.

And secondly, the terms of the form $y_3^2 + z_3^2 - 4 x_3^2$ are the key things to look for, and these should be simplified as
$$
y_3^2 + z_3^2 - 4 x_3^2
=
r_3^2 - 5 x_3^2.
$$
Once this separation is done, it is much easier to break those two terms into separate groups and simplify them individually.

Comment: Not that it's meaningful to me, but you could write the 2nd factor, symmetric in 1,2, as $\vec r_3 M \vec r_3$, with *M* being the dyadic $M= \vec r_1\cdot \vec r_2 {\mathbb I} -5 \overleftarrow {r}_1 \vec r_2$ .